# jquery blockui doesn't work in IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using the BlockUI plugin to prevent user action on a page when a hyperlink/button is clicked on a page. The page is created using frame. It works on Firefox/chrome (only on the targeted frame, center), but not IE .

Here's my code, tried with both a hyperlink and button. same result, doesn't work:

```
<tr>
     <td>
         <INPUT type="button" id="blocktest" name="block" value="block" onclick="blockPage()"/>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript file for hyperlink:

```
function blockPage() {
    //alert("hello....");

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.blockUI();
    });
}
```

Note: jQuery blockUi Version 2.66.0-2013.10.09

Comment: Why is your jQuery $(document).ready in a function?

Comment: when my will trigger it shows wait msg..

Comment: with out my ready method it also working  in chrome/ff